# create-react-app with typescript compiles functions to something very strange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I've encountered some very, very strange error in my create-react-app application (`react-scripts@2.1.1`) with typescript (at this point and have no idea if it's relevant or not - error persists through even if I rewrite affected files to plain vanilla js):

I have a very basic plain utility functions to compose action types for redux:

```
// ...../utils.ts
export type Type = string;
export type Types = {
  [key: string]: Type;
};

export const typeWithPrefix = (prefix: string, type: string): string => {
  return `${prefix}/${type}`;
};

export const typesWithPrefix = (prefix: string, types: Array<string>): Types => {
  return types.reduce((result: Types, type) => {
    result[type] = typeWithPrefix(prefix, type);

    return result;
  }, {});
};

export const asyncTypes = (type: string): Array<string> => {
  return [
    type,
    `${type}_START`,
    `${type}_SUCCESS`,
    `${type}_FAIL`,
    `${type}_FINALLY`
   ];
};
```

Usage:

```
// ....auth/types.ts
import { typesWithPrefix, asyncTypes } from '../../utils';

export default typesWithPrefix('auth', [
    ...asyncTypes('SIGN_IN'), 
    ...asyncTypes('SIGN_OUT')
]);

// nothing fancy, plain object:
// => {SIGN_IN: 'auth/SIGN_IN', SIGN_IN_START: 'auth/SIGN_IN_START'....}
```

In development it works pretty much as you would expect - some utils are imported, plain object with types constants exported;

But as soon as I build application with `react-scripts build` I see strange thing in browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

Inspecting compiled and minified source shows that `asyncTypes` is actually an Object - [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unnkx.png).
As far as my understanding goes in build time one of compilers or minifies decided to fold function calls to constants but how and why - beyond me, especially without ejecting from react-scripts...

So if any of you have any ideas what the hell is going on and how it can be avoided - I would be very, very glad to hear because frankly I'm out of ideas..

Comment: So, the search continues; as it turns out the problem is not the function but with...some strange import/export issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since nobody has any clue I'll answer close this one since I *did* solve the problem with build but I am not sure how and why:

turns out code above

```
// ....auth/types.ts
import { typesWithPrefix, asyncTypes } from '../../utils';

typesWithPrefix(// ...
```

*does* work in development but *does not* in production;

but the code

```
// ....auth/types.ts
import * as utils from '../../utils';

utils.typesWithPrefix(// ...
```

*does* works both in development and production, despite the fact thats just pure functions as named exports and reexports in `index.ts` files.

I would love to dig deeper and uncover this mystery but this will require to eject and I really, really don't won't to do it until I can avoid it...